# What is the "previous system" folder I have in my root directory after ML installation and is it safe to delete?

Tags: macos, upgrade

What is the "Previous System" folder I now have have in my root directory after upgrading Mountain Lion and is it safe to delete? It's 172MB of mostly random font files

Comment: which OS did you update from? I upgraded from Snow Leopard and curiously don't have that folder.

Comment: Lion ---> Mountain Lion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to delete that folder. I did it and to date I haven't faced any issues.

Comment: Happy i could help, but i am surprised someone down-voted it!!

Comment: Sorry I should have posted an explanation. I downvoted because this does not really answer the core question of *what* the folder is... and there is also no source suggesting it's safe to delete the folder (just your own experience as anecdotal evidence).

Comment: @Jtbandes it depends on the perspective, i understood the concern of the asker (hopefully, since he accepted it) that is about the safety of deleting the folder and i told him about my experience ( i also do a lot of testing ).  Anyways thanks for the vote :-)